# EF Core Expression in Select with multiple parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

So I have a property that I will parse into the `Select` method. This will work with one parameter but can I make it work with two, and if I can't what would be the approach? I am using EF Core 3.1.8. with the SqlServer 3.1.8 package.

```
private static Expression<Func<ClassOne, bool, ClassTwo> Summary
{
  get
  {
    return (p, myBool) => new ClassTwo()
    {
      ListOfItems = p.ListWithMyItems.Where(i => i.Field == myBool)
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Expression. I query with this method.

```
public async Task<ClassTwo> GetSummaryAsync(bool isAdmin = false)
{
  return await _context
    .DatabaseTable // type of DbSet<ClassOne>
    .Select(Summary) // how do I parse isAdmin to Summary?
    .ToListAsync();
}
```

So I hope you can see my problem. I want to avoid the where clause in the method because I have at least 10 other methods that use this `Expression` in different ways and also in my case it would become an nested `Where` which is not possible which straight querying. I don't want C# to do the work for me, let SQL Server handle that.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

I tried this in the `GetSummaryAsync` but it is not possible:

```
.Select(i => (i, isAdmin))
```

Comment: Did you try write your own extension method?

Comment: @MustafaArslan no I did not. What are you thinking of exactly?

Comment: I answered it below.

Answer (score 0):

Define extension method

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IQueryable<ClassTwo> Summary(this IQueryable<ClassOne> one, bool myBool)
    {
        return one.Select(p => new ClassTwo
        {
            ListOfItems = p.ListWithMyItems.Where(i => i.Field == myBool)
        });
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
public async Task<ClassTwo> GetSummaryAsync(bool isAdmin = false)
{
  return await _context
    .DatabaseTable 
    .Summary(isAdmin)
    .ToListAsync();
}
```